# How can I write a select statement for this use case?

Tags: sql, select

Please help me compose a SELECT statement. I have these two tables:

```
Table1                 Table2
----------------       ------------------------------------------------
ID  |  PName   |       |  ID  | NameID  |   DateActive  | HoursActive |
----------------       ------------------------------------------------
1   |  Neil    |       |  1   |    1    |   8/2/2013    |      3      |
2   |  Mark    |       |  2   |    1    |   8/3/2013    |      4      |
3   |  Onin    |       |  3   |    2    |   8/2/2013    |      2      |
----------------       |  4   |    2    |   8/6/2013    |      5      |
                       |  5   |    3    |   8/7/2013    |      1      |
                       |  6   |    3    |   8/8/2013    |     10      |
                       ------------------------------------------------
```

And I just want to retrieve the earliest DateActive but no duplicate PName. Like this:

```
PName    |  DateActive  | HoursActive  |
----------------------------------------
Neil     |  8/2/2013    |       3      |
Mark     |  8/2/2013    |       2      |
Onin     |  8/7/2013    |       1      |
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you've tried yourself to solve the problem. We try to be helpful here at StackOverflow, but we are not a code writing service. We expect some effort on your part first. Questions asking for code should at least show you understand the problem and have attempted to solve it, and while it's very nice that you've provided sample data and the output you'd like, you've not shown an attempt to actually write a query yourself.

Comment: Which RDBMS -- there are generic solutions, but there are also DBMS specific ones...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might do it.  You need to find the min date for each NameID first, then join back to the table to get the hours.

```
SELECT
       PName, MaxDate as DataActive, HoursActive 
From 
       Table1 t1
    inner Join Table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.NameID 
    Inner Join (Select min(DateActive) as mindate, NameID from Table2 Group by NameID) as t3  on t3.mindate = t2.ActiveDate and t3.NameID = t2.NameId
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be a pretty standard solution:

```
select t.pname, 
    t2.dateactive, 
    t2.hoursac
from table1 t
    join table2 t2 on t.id = t2.nameid
    join (
        select nameid, min(dateactive) mindateactive
        from table2 
        group by nameid
    ) t3 on t2.nameid =  t3.name 
            and t3.mindateactive = t2.dateactive
```

If you are using an RDBMS that supports partition by statements, then this would be more efficient:

```
select   pname, dateactive, HoursActive 
from (
    select t.pname, 
        t2.dateactive, 
        t2.hoursactive,
        rank() over (partition by t.id order by t2.dateactive) rownum 
    from table1 t
        join table2 t2 on t.id = t2.nameid
) t
where rownum = 1
```